# How can I get the name of the current terminal from command-line?

Tags: command-line

Is there a possibility to get the type of terminal with a command?

If I'm using `gnome-terminal`, the output should be `gnome-terminal` or something similar. It would be also nice to get the version of the terminal.

**Update**

```
ps -aux | grep `ps -p $$ -o ppid=`
```

will output something like this:

```
user     4239  0.0  0.7 292708 15744 pts/8    Sl   11:39   0:02 xfce4-terminal
user     4800  0.0  0.0   6176   820 pts/0    S+   12:23   0:00 grep --color=auto  4239
```

This will also work with xterm, but how do I get only the name (`xfce4-terminal` in this case)?

Comment: I just updated my answer with a different and better approach. If you have the time, have a look and let me know if it also works for you.

Comment: Thanks but first problem with rxvt -> `window 31457282 has no pid associated with it` (tested on Lubuntu)

Comment: Oh? Damn, that's weird. I tested under Cinnamon.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

##Original version

One way to do this is to get the parent process of your current shell session and from there the name of the terminal.

1. Get the parent of the current shell process. The bash variable `$$` is the PID of your current shell, so we can give that as a query to `ps` (`-p $$`) and ask it tp print the PID of the parent process (`-o ppid=`, the trailing `=` is to avoid printing column headers):

   ```
    $ ps -p $$ -o ppid=
    544
   ```

So, the PID of my shell's parent is `544`.

2. Get the process associated with that PID and print its command line

   ```
    $ ps -p 544 o args=
    /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/terminator
   ```

The above output will depend on what terminal emulator you are using, I am using `terminator`.

3. Combine everything in a single command

   ```
    ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) -o args=
   ```
4. Use that to get the version

   ```
    $(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) o args=) --version
    terminator 0.97
   ```
5. Add a little function to your `~/.bashrc` that returns the name and version of the terminal emulator you're using (this works for most common terminal emulators):

   ```bash
    which_term(){
        term=$(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) -o args=);
        found=0;
        case $term in
            *gnome-terminal*)
                found=1
                echo "gnome-terminal " $(dpkg -l gnome-terminal | awk '/^ii/{print $3}')
                ;;
            *lxterminal*)
                found=1
                echo "lxterminal " $(dpkg -l lxterminal | awk '/^ii/{print $3}')
                ;;
            rxvt*)
                found=1
                echo "rxvt " $(dpkg -l rxvt | awk '/^ii/{print $3}')
                ;;
            ## Try and guess for any others
            *)
                for v in '-version' '--version' '-V' '-v'
                do
                    $term "$v" &>/dev/null && eval $term $v && found=1 && break
                done
                ;;
        esac
        ## If none of the version arguments worked, try and get the 
        ## package version
        [ $found -eq 0 ] && echo "$term " $(dpkg -l $term | awk '/^ii/{print $3}')    
    }
   ```

You can now get the name of the terminal and also pass any option you like to it (such as `--version`.

Some examples using different terminals:

1. `xterm`

   ```
    $ which_term
    XTerm(297)
   ```
2. `terminator`

   ```
    $ which_term 
    terminator 0.97
   ```
3. `rxvt`, this one has none of the `-V`, `-version` or `--version` flags so no version info is printed.

   ```
    $  which_term
    rxvt  1:2.7.10-5
   ```
4. `gnome-terminal`.

   ```
    $ which_term
    gnome-terminal  3.10.1-1
   ```
5. `konsole`

   ```
    $ which_term
    Qt: 4.8.6
    KDE Development Platform: 4.11.3
    Konsole: 2.11.3
   ```
6. `lxterminal`

   ```
    $ which_term
    lxterminal  0.1.11-4
   ```
7. `xfce4-terminal`

   ```
    $ which_term
    xfce4-terminal 0.6.2 (Xfce 4.10)

    Copyright (c) 2003-2012
        The Xfce development team. All rights reserved.

    Written by Benedikt Meurer <benny@xfce.org>
    and Nick Schermer <nick@xfce.org>.

    Please report bugs to <http://bugzilla.xfce.org/>.
   ```

---

### New and improved

The above approach is not that trustworthy though. It will choke when you run your shell after `su`ing to another user or when your terminal is aliased to something and various other cases. Since we are obviously working with X programs here, a better way might be to use something like `xdotool` (installable with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`) to get the information instead:

```
perl -lpe 's/\0/ /g' /proc/$(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getactivewindow))/cmdline
```

The above will print the command line used to launch the currently active window. Since your terminal will, presumably, be active, that is the command it will show. This means that for most terminal emulators, you can safely assume that the 1st field returned is the terminal name:

```
$ which_term 
lxterminal
```

This means that getting the version is trivial. For example

```
$ dpkg -l $(which_term) | awk '/^ii/{print $3}'
0.1.11-4
```

Not so for `gnome-terminal`:

```
$ which_term 
/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
```

or `terminator`:

```
$ which_term
/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/terminator
```

So, we can make it a little more complex (there are some bashisms here, this one is not portable):

```
which_term(){
    term=$(perl -lpe 's/\0/ /g' \
           /proc/$(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getactivewindow))/cmdline)

    ## Enable extended globbing patterns
    shopt -s extglob
    case $term in
        ## If this terminal is a python or perl program,
        ## then the emulator's name is likely the second 
        ## part of it
        */python*|*/perl*    )
         term=$(basename "$(readlink -f $(echo "$term" | cut -d ' ' -f 2))")
         version=$(dpkg -l "$term" | awk '/^ii/{print $3}')
         ;;
        ## The special case of gnome-terminal
        *gnome-terminal-server* )
          term="gnome-terminal"
        ;;
        ## For other cases, just take the 1st
        ## field of $term
        * )
          term=${term/% */}
        ;;
     esac
     version=$(dpkg -l "$term" | awk '/^ii/{print $3}')
     echo "$term  $version"
}
```

This works for all cases I tested on.

Comment: @Xubu-Tur hmm, I only tried by launching each terminal from another terminal manually and it worked fine. I'm guessing your desktop environment menus have a different path or somehow differ in how they launch the terminals. I might be able to give you something better if you tell me exactly how you launched them and what error you got. If you launched from a menu, check what command the menu item runs.

Comment: @Xubu-Tur don't add a screenshot. Just paste the error message into your question. Same for whatever command the menu item launches. Don't expect me to manually copy it from a picture!

Comment: You can just use `$PPID` to get the PID of the parent process.

Comment: @nyuszika7h yes you can and +1 for that but I'd rather not. I just checked and it's not available in `ksh` or `tcsh`. It's a very good idea for the bash family though since it is much simpler than my approach.

Comment: It's definitely available in `ksh93` and `mksh`.

Comment: @nyuszika7h yes indeed, sorry, it is not available in `fish`, `csh` and `tcsh`. That `ksh` should have been `csh`.

Comment: Those shells have different syntax anyway, and most people here will expect bash, as it's the default.

Comment: Think I spotted a typo :)

`$(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) o args=) --version`

The second `o` should be `-o`:
`$(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) -o args=) --version`

Comment: Both work, actually, @s6mike. The `o` (without the `-`) is BSD format and the `ps` that ships with most Linux systems, including Ubuntu, supports both `-o` and `o`. But still, you're right that it's confusing and it's cleaner to use the same format for both, so I edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
basename "$(cat "/proc/$PPID/comm")"
```

`$PPID` is the PID of the shell's parent process. `comm` means *command*. It may or may not be a full path, so we use `basename` to strip the path if needed.

#### Caveats

These probably apply to at least some of the other answers too.

- `comm` is technically `argv[0]`, which can actually be an arbitrary string. But in general, you should be able to rely on it for this particular case.
- This won't work as expected if you connect over SSH or use `tmux`, `screen` or something similar.

Comment: This is very nice +1, but on the terminator terminal i get only `termin` as output.

Comment: I don't know why, it's probably Terminator's fault.

Comment: It's because it's run as a python script I think. It's really annoying.

Comment: Please note that `$PPID` is not standard in all shells. e.g. in `tcsh` I get: `PPID: Undefined variable.`

Answer (score 9):

Try this,

```
ps -aux | grep `ps -p $$ -o ppid=` | awk 'NR==1{print $11}'
```

OR

```
ps -aux | grep `ps -p $$ -o ppid=` | awk 'NR==1{print $NF}'
```

Comment: The first fails on `rxvt` and `terminator` and the second fails on `uxterm` and `gnome-terminal` (it prints `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server`). They will all fail (as will mine) if you are using an su session.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You can try the following command:</strike>

```
$ dpkg-query -W $COLORTERM
gnome-terminal  3.6.2-0ubuntu1
```

**Update** (thanks to OP and Avinash Raj):

```
$ dpkg-query -W $(ps -aux | grep "`ps -p $$ -o ppid=`" | awk 'NR==1{print $11}' | xargs basename)
rxvt    1:2.7.10-5
```

Comment: I think he wants to know it for the active terminal session :) So if he is using "putty" at that time ...

Comment: No not over "putty" but whats about xterm, with this command i get also `gnome-terminal  3.6.2-0ubuntu1l` in xterm?

Comment: This does not print the terminal you are using at the moment. It prints whatever has been set s the default $COLORTERM, that has nothing to do with what you're using at the time.

Comment: The Update works well also with xterm and shows the version and the name.

Comment: All the credit goes to @Avinash and you for the right command. I've just added the version.

Answer (score 3):

Another (not perfect) possibility is:

```
xprop -id $WINDOWID WM_CLASS | cut -d" " -f3 | sed 's/^.\(.*\)..$/\1/'
```

But this does not work with lxterminal because there is the environment variable `$WINDOWID` empty...

Terminator shows the name "x-terminal-emulator".

Answer (score 3):

The name of the terminal might be set in your environment variables.

```
echo $TERM
```

Examples:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

Comment: -1, It specifies _what sort of terminal_ you're using, not the terminal itself. So for instance, I'm using Konsole, but `echo $TERM` prints `xterm-256color`.

Answer (score 0):

The current terminal can also be detected via an escape sequence: The [Device Attributes (Secondary DA)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29939719)

For example in bash:

```sh
read -s -dc -p $'\E[>c' da;da=${da##$'\E'[>};echo "${da//;/ }"
```

This returns only some kind of id - and sadly I don't know an official list that translate these to the actual names.

---

For a real implementation, that translates some known ids to terminal names, see this example bash script:
https://github.com/mintty/utils/blob/master/terminal