# Can I find what application the shell is running in?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm writing a shell script that spawns off new tabs, which I've noticed is slightly different in `gnome-terminal` compared to `terminator` -is there a way to find what application the shell is running in, to format the commands for a particular terminal:

```
if [[ $term == "terminator" ]] ; then
        terminator --new-tab -p PROD -x "(command sequence)"
elif  [[ $term == "gnome-terminal" ]] 
    gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=PROD -- (command sequence)
else
    # else what?
    echo "Unknown terminal"
fi
```

How do I find `$term`?

Comment: Related: [How can I get the name of the current terminal from command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476641/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-terminal-from-command-line)

Comment: Thanks for that!!        .